# Does Wandering Archaic trigger if the spell is countered?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Wandering Archaic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wandering%20Archaic) is in play, a spell is played and countered while the Wandering Archaic's ability is still on the stack, what happens when the Wandering Arachic trigger resolves? Does it fizzle or does it create a copy despite the original spell being countered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the triggered ability does not target, it will resolve and use last known information about the copied spell. See for example the ruling on [Mirari](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirari).